# Accurate Web-Api requests/second performance counter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, performancecounter

I need to be able to query my web-api solution through an Admin Api that I have written and find the requests per second that it is currently receiving/handling. The best I have come up with so far is to use the system performance counter defined like this:

```
var sample = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Applications", "Requests/Sec", "__Total__", true)
```

The only problem with this method, is that in order to retrieve a value from this counter, I must use the `nextValue()` method which requires you to call it twice with a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` in order to get an accurate, non-zero reading.

I need to be able to query the solution on a 1-5 second basis so sleeping for 1000 milliseconds is not a great option for performance, even if it was an async call. Is there a better way to do what im trying to do here?

Thanks in advance for the help!

sample of current working code:

```
var sampleCounter = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Applications", "Requests/Sec", "__Total__", true);
sampleCounter.nextValue();
Thread.sleep(1000);
return sampleCounter.nextValue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying every 1-5 seconds, keep your counter alive somewhere global, and query it once a second?

Comment: would i have to religiously call nextValue() on the counter on a 1000ms basis? Or could it just be global, and queried whenever?

Comment: It basically averages the reads between the calls. So you want to have it read on a regular basis, and depending how critical transient nature of the result here you can average it.

Since you mentioned you want to read every 1-5 seconds, I would just create a counter, read it every second (or so, that's not too critical) and return a rolling average of say the last 5 results.